Vue3 Caching Problems after IIS Server Deployments
I have the following problem after deploying a new version to my vue 3 application. The problem is that every site the user has visited in his current session is still cached in his browser even though i already have set all no-store, no-caching, etc. header and i can confirm via browser that all files have that header set. I already give an hash value to all new files during build and remove the old files. I guess cause i dynamically import the files via vue router they get cached automatically and i cant find a way to stop that. I even tried to append a date to the import statements with a timestamp but it seems like that is just run once and thats it. Im getting kinda clueless and dont know what another way could be. I dont want to tell my users to manually refresh after deployment every time. What could i do?
Setup: Using Vite + Vue 3 + vue-router Deployment on IIS Server + Newest Edge Browser (Chrome based)
vite.config.ts
const hash = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 10000;
..
build: {
    rollupOptions: {
        output: {
            entryFileNames: `[name]` + hash + `.js`,
            chunkFileNames: `[name]` + hash + `.js`,
            assetFileNames: `[name]` + hash + `.[ext]`
        }
    },
    headers: {
        // Cache-Control für alle statischen Ressourcen setzen
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate'
    }
}

web.config (on IIS)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <!-- URL-Rewriting für Vue.js History Mode -->
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="VueHistoryMode" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <!-- Optional: Ausschluss von spezifischen API-Pfaden von der Rewrite-Regel -->
                        <!-- <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/api" negate="true" /> -->
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
 
        <!-- HTTP-Header für das Verhindern von Caching -->
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate" />
                <add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" />
                <add name="Expires" value="0" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
 
        <!-- Statische Inhalte und deren Cache-Einstellungen -->
        <staticContent>
            <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
            <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
            <remove fileExtension=".json" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
            <remove fileExtension=".webp" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".webp" mimeType="image/webp" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Router.ts
// This is how i import the components
...
component: () => import('@/home/Home.vue'),
...

 // This is working like i want it to be but not on sites the user has already loaded in that tab before deployment
router.onError((error, to) => {
    if (error.message.includes('Failed to fetch dynamically imported module')
        || error.message.includes('Importing a module script failed')) {
        console.log(to?.fullPath);
        if (!to?.fullPath) {
            window.location.reload();
        } else {
            window.location.href = to.fullPath;
        }
    }
});

I need an easy way to automatically update the site for my users, best case as soon as they change the site they are currently working in. I dont want to tell my users to manually reload the site. After reloading all is fine, cause then the newest site is shown.
What i have tried:

add hash to vite.config.ts
add cache control headers to vite config + iis config
add common http response headers and set expire web content -> immediately


Have you considered adding a timestamp as a query param to each request?

Double-check that all necessary headers are applied correctly across all file types, this can be enforced in web.config if you're using IIS.
